# How can I build and use a docker image with a buildpack that simply runs a script with arguments?

Tags: python, docker, buildpack

I've been experimenting with using `pack` to build a docker image. I'm quite happy with using a Dockerfile if that is the better approach.

I have a single python script that uses `click` to parse arguments. In a Dockerfile, I'd specify as the ENTRYPOINT something like `["python", "myscript.py"]` and then I could run:

```
docker run MYCONTAINER myarg1 myarg2
```

and replace my script with the `docker run`.

I am attempting to get the same functionality using buildpacks and a `Procfile`. Here is what I have, roughly, in the profile:

```
web: python myscript.py
```

However, when I try running the resulting successfully built image using docker run (eg., `docker run MYCONTAINER myarg1 myarg2`), I get errors like:

```
python myscript.py: python myscript.py: command not found
```

Running the same docker run without the arguments works as expected and prints the help for my command-line script and exits.

What am I missing? My google-foo has failed me...

Comment: It should put `python` on the path, so that's a little odd. Maybe try a few variations, like `python3 myscript.py` (assuming you're using Python 3) or `python /workspace/myscript.py` (your files live under `/workspace`). You should be able to run the default process type with arguments: https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#default-process-type-with-additional-arguments